# Difference between one to one function and one to one correspondence

Tags: functions

I am confused in the difference between one to one function and one to one correspondence. Please help me out to distinguish between the two. 
Thanks

Comment: In the case of your previous question it's the same. In general, a function is always defined on a set. A one to one correspondence can also be given for objects in [classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28mathematics%29).

Comment: See [this math.SE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63154/how-did-one-to-one-come-to-mean-injective).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say (hand waveingly) a one to one function is a mapping from A to B that puts A & B into one-to-one correspondence with each other, for one to one and function as defined in your previous questions.

Answer (score 3):

a one to one function can be injective or bijective but a one to one correspondence can only be bijective

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps you understand things a bit better. I too had the same question a while ago...
**Types of Mappings/Functions**
  a.    **Injective mapping (injection)**: **one-to-one mapping** = is a function that preserves distinctness: it never maps distinct elements of its domain to the same element of its codomain.
  b.    **Surjection**: onto mapping = a function f from a set X to a set Y is surjective (or onto), or a surjection, if for every element y in the codomain Y of f there is at least one element x in the domain X of f such that f(x) = y. It is not required that x be unique; the function f may map one or more elements of X to the same element of Y. 
  c.    **Bijective mapping (bijection)**: one-to-one and onto mapping = **one-to-one correspondence** 
[NOTE: bijectivity (one-to-one **correspondence**) is a necessary condition for functions to have inverses, whereas injectivity (one-to-one **mapping**) solely will not help in guaranteeing inverses].
 [image: Pictorial representations of these mappings]

Answer (score 0):

1. one to one means injective (a mapping $f$ which maps distinct
   elements of its domain to distinct elements of its codomain, i.e. $f(x) \neq f(y)$
   whenever $x \neq y$ )
2. one to one correspondence means bijective (a mapping $f$ which is injective AND for every element $y$ in the codomain of $f$, there exists an element of $x$ in the domain of $f$ such that $f(x) = y$ )